# Return function value to range argument step

Tags: python, function, range

Hi can some one point me some guidance, i pretend to pass the value of function schema to a variable that will be used as the argument step inside the range module.
i hope its clear .. sorry the newbie guys.
after some trials i got the edit fine.

```
import os
import sys


def schema(x):
    if x == 'M':
        step=1
    else:
        step=2
        return step

def main():
    left_start = 1
    left_end = 9
    sch = schema('M')

    range1= range(left_start,left_end,sch)
    if 2 in range1:
        print "In range"
    else:
        print "Missing in range"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: And what, praytell, is the problem?

Comment: the problem is TypeError: range() integer step argument expected, got NoneType.

Comment: That's because a function returns None by default. Your schema function doesn't return when `x == 'M'`, therefore it is passing `None` to `range()`.

Comment: You should accept aix's answer as it is the most complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a problem with indentation. The following:

```
def schema(x):
    if x == 'M':
        step=1
    else:
        step=2
        return step
```

should read

```
def schema(x):
    if x == 'M':
        step=1
    else:
        step=2
    return step
```

Otherwise, the function returns `None` when `x == 'M'`.

A more concise way to write that function is:

```
def schema(x):
    return 1 if x == 'M' else 2
```

Comment: Uau Thx aix .. what a support, it just worked perfect you are all great.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to do the following:

```
def schema(x):
    if x == 'M':
        step=1
    else:
        step=2
    return step
```

Notice how the `return step` is indented to the same level as the `if` statement. In your code, the `return step` will only run in the `else` case. In the case where `x == 'M'`, your code would return `None` from `schema()`.

My suggested code will run the `return step` in either case.

Comment: Hi Greg just edited the code ... still receiving TypeError: range() integer step argument expected, got NoneType.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in indentation your code:

```
def schema(x):
    if x == 'M':
        step=1
    else:
        step=2
        return step
```

it should as:

```
def schema(x):
    if x == 'M':
        step=1
    else:
        step=2
    return step
```

in your code the step is returned IF and only if x!='M'.